# SwiftUI: UIHostingController<?> generic?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am doing this:

```
class PortraitViewController: UIHostingController<MyView> {
    
    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .portrait
    }
    
}
```

then when I instantiate it I do this:

```
let vc = PortraitViewController(rootView: MyView())
```

All works great.

I would like to create a fully generic `PortraitViewController` that could accept any `View` and not just `MyView`.

I am not sure how to change the `UIHostingController<MyView>` to make it work with any view. I tried `UIHostingController<View>` but it's not working.

How can I make it so `let vc = PortraitViewController(rootView: MyView())` can work with another View and not just `MyView`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can constrain the generic to just a `View` type:

```
class PortraitViewController<T:View>: UIHostingController<T>
```